# Why is this curl command not working?

Tags: go

Hi there I just want to create a simple golang applications, which posts a new dent at identi.ca using

```
curl -u username:password http://example.com/api/statuses/update.xml -d status='Howdy!' -d lat='30.468' -d long='-94.743'
```

This is my code so far and imho this should work, but actually it isn't working, does anybody know how to fix this?

**EDIT:** Nope: I don't get any error messages :/

```
package main

import(
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "bufio"
        "exec"
)
func main() {

var err os.Error
var username string

print("Username: ")
_, err = fmt.Scanln(&username)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

var password string
print("Password: ")
_, err = fmt.Scanln(&password)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

var status string
print("Status: ")
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin);
status, err = in.ReadString('\n');
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}

exec.Command("curl -u " + username + ":" + password + "https://identi.ca/api/statuses/update.xml -d status='" + status +  "'" + "-d source='API'").Run()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it isn't working"? Do you get an error? If so, which?

Comment: Nope, I dont get an error, but I think there something wrong with the curl command :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exec.Command()` doesn't take the whole command line as a single argument. You need to call it as:

```
exec.Command("curl", "-u", username+":"+password, ...url..., "-d", "status="+status, "-d", "source=API").Run()
```

How do you know if you get an error? You don't check the return value of `Run()`.

You should actually separate the command creation from running it. This way you can set the process's stdout and stderr to something besides `/dev/null`, e.g.

```
c := exec.Command("curl", "-u", username+":"+password, "https://identi.ca/api/statuses/update.xml", "-d", "status="+status, "-d", "source=API")
c.Stdout = os.Stdout
c.Stderr = os.Stderr
err = c.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}
```

Comment: When I add the second code I always get in output, even if the dent was published succsesfull...

Comment: What you could do instead of connecting `c.Stdout` to `os.Stdout` is use the `Output()` method of `Cmd` which is similar, but return the output of the command in a byte slice.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/ggd3ww3ZKcI), `exec.Command` doesn't split the command line arguments like your normal shell environment does (bash, cmd, etc).

So in addition to filling in the parameters as

```
exec.Command("your_executable", "-switch1", "value1", "-switch2", "value2")
```

you can have bash or cmd (Windows) help you

```
exec.Command("cmd","/C", "your_executable -switch1 value1 -switch2 value2")
```

or you can split the argument string yourself ([ref](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/XpZ9W3kicjE))

```
arguments := "-switch1 value1 -switch2 value2"

arg_slice := strings.Split(arguments, " ")

exec.Command("your_executable", arg_slice...)
```

This is most convenient, since you may build up the `arguments` string at run-time.

Comment: `strings.Split(arguments, " ")` won't actually work all the time with curl. Since you can have spaces within your header values, etc it will break